# Select element from json dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I have a an associative array in php that i parse to get json from it (json_encode) then i store the result in a javascript var

```
var myArray = <?php print json_encode($phpArray); ?>;
```

Now whene the user hit a button i should choose another element from the array dynamically, for example, i chose a random first element :

```
var an_element = myArray.a2.link;
```

-'a2' is an array in the main array

-'link' is an element in the a2 array.

So now whene the user hit my button, i want to choose a random  other array id (for example a5, a9, etc.)
I tried this :

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*101); // choose random number
var newRandomArrayID= "a"+randomnumber;
an_element = myArray.newRandomArrayID.link;
```

It doesn't works, it says  myArray.newRandomArrayID is undefined.
Anyone can help?
Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `[]` indexing to find properties by name:

```
an_element = myArray[newRandomArrayID].link;
```

Otherwise JS is looking for a property actually called `newRandomArrayID` on `myArray` rather than using the value of the variable to lookup the property.

Comment: K.O Prefect it works :) i can't check it as answered till 10 min passe (stackoverflow rules) :p Thank you